# html5 canvas hand cursor problems

Tags: javascript, html

I'm playing around with html5 and some javascript to make a minor sketchpad. Whenever I click down on the canvas in chrome, the cursor becomes a text cursor. I have tried putting cursor: hand in the css, but that doesn't seem to work. This has got to be an easy thing, but I look it up and can't find it anywhere

Comment: Well, first off it's "cursor: pointer" not "cursor: hand"...

Answer (score 18):

Use the disable text selection on the canvas. This works like a charm.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; } // ie
canvas.onmousedown = function () { return false; } // mozilla
```

Cheers,
Kris

Comment: Beautiful! I'd been looking for a solution to this for a while, who would have dreamed it was so simple? For the edification of the interwebs: the "return false" method also prevents the cursor from changing to an i-beam in Chrome. I know Atwood dislikes people showing gratitude verbally in their comments, but Thank You anyway!

Comment: For webkit browsers you can also add `body { -webkit-user-select: none; }` to your CSS.

Comment: nice! That saved me quite a bit of time!

Answer (score 12):

While the other guys were absolutely bang on referring you to the quirksmode reference, that won't fix the problem you are having, and essentially you need to implement a variation of Kris's answer.

In my own implementation, I found that preventing default behaviour in the mousedown event was all that was required to stop that pesky text selection cursor:

```
function handleMouseDown(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();

  // you can change the cursor if you want
  // just remember to handle the mouse up and put it back :)
  evt.target.style.cursor = 'move';

  // rest of code goes here
}

document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown, false);
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Damon.

Answer (score 7):

Use `pointer` for your cursor property instead, like this:

```
canvas { cursor: pointer; }
```

`hand` is IE/Opera specific, [you can see a full list of which cursors work in which browsers here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html).

Comment: particularly this note is helpful in the mentioned link http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html#note

Comment: i put that in but still doing the same thing. Check it here: http://p-func.com/html5_test/test2.html

Comment: @pfunc - I can't debug your page directly, it has a few invalid properties that needs correcting... `<script>` tags need to be `<script></script>`, they can't be self closing like `<script />`.  Also there's an extra `<body>` tag in there...can't debug funky behavior until it's valid :)

Comment: thanks, this is what happens when a flash developer tries to go back to html. I chnaged those and still happening.