# When I click on a canvas and drag my mouse, the cursor changes to a text-selection cursor. How can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, mouse-cursor

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MZ9Xm/

Note: The following occurs in Chrome 22.0.1221.1, but not in Firefox 14.0.1. [Ubuntu linux]

Move your mouse to the top canvas and press and hold the mouse button. Drag the mouse, and the cursor will change to a text-selection mouse cursor (I-bar). This does not happen if there are no other elements on the page.

I've messed around with setting user-selection to none, but have not had any luck.

Comment: Linking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4945874/94197), some of the comments discuss this bug.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can bind a mousedown event in your canvas to prevent default behavior.

Something like:

```
// with jQuery
$( "#canvasId" ).mousedown(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

// without jQuery
document.getElementById( "canvasId" ).onmousedown = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MZ9Xm/1/

You will need to test this to see if there is some side effect in what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [CSS `cursor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor) ?

```js
canvas {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It should display the default cursor.

Comment: Yes, I tried this but no dice. Try it out in the fiddle. The cursor still changes to a text-selection cursor. (In Chrome 22.0.1221.1. I don't have to do anything at all to get it to work with Firefox 14.0.1.)

Comment: It should be a Chrome bug...  
Anyway, they had the same problem in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659999/html5-canvas-hand-cursor-problems) and it seems they resolved it.

Comment: Great! I found the answer there (it was Damon's answer). I'm not sure about the protocol here. I guess if you change this answer to link to damon's, I will accept it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the stackoverfow's edit button doesn't works: i get a [beautiful error page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11805366/edit) :-p Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var canvasEls = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas'),
    preventHl = function () { return false; },
    i = 0;

while (i < canvasEls.length) {
    canvasEls[i].onmousedown = preventHl;
    i += 1;
}
```

Returning false will prevent default actions such as highlighting from occurring.