# Change cursor over HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, image, canvas, mouse-cursor

I have a canvas in my site and an image rotation function. So I want to change the mouse cursor when I am trying to rotate the image. I tried this one for the beginning,

```
 <canvas id="draw" style="cursor: url(img/rotate.cur)">
```

but I did not manage to make it work. What I get in Chrome is 'Invalid property value'. What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659999/html5-canvas-hand-cursor-problems